# how to create raw volume indicator in tradingview?

Tags: pine-script

I want an indicator which will show raw volume amount (Volume*price) for a specific time period... for example if during 1 hour was sold 5 bitcoin for $20,000 raw volume =$100,000

how make this kind of script? I want to see the raw volume chart

Answer (score 0):

The pine script v5 should have ta.volume function to give you the volume data. Also, there is a really good youtube channel "Daily Crypto Analysis". The guy has several insightful videos on this particular topic (volume*price).